# Excel and pay days

Tags: excel

Cell F2 holds the year. I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically change the days for the pay periods for a given year. We always have 26, and the next one is 12/12. But if I type a new year in f2, I wanted it to show all the fridays I am paid that year.

I have 26 cells setup for it.

Maybe a formula that uses the the first date in jan that we are paid and add f2 - 2015 with a date formula?

= date(2015,1,9) + year(f2 - 2015) but next year it is on a different day.

Comment: And on that example formula, I meant to add + 14 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the year is in F2 then you can get the first pay day of any future year with this formula

`=CEILING(DATE(F2,1,1)-DATE(2014,12,12),14)+DATE(2014,12,12)`

Then just add 14 to that for subsequent paydays in the year, so if you have that formula in F4 then F5 should be just

`=F4+14`

format in required date format and copy that formula down the column as far as required

Comment: Thanks Barry Houdini.

Comment: I'm so intrigued with the formula. I learned a new function with ceiling.

Comment: Basically, ceiling is returning how many days since the payday, so 28 in 2015 and 390ish in 2016, etc. Then it adds to the the date we know that is a payday. Nice!